# How to change the order of function body execution?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am studying the Emacs-Lisp by following the introduction.

I can understand the below defun print out a list in left-to-right order because the print command comes before recursion (as I understood):

```
  (defun print-elements-recursively (list)
   "Print each element of LIST on a line of its own.
 Uses recursion."
   (when list                            ; do-again-test
         (print (car list))              ; body
         (print-elements-recursively     ; recursive call
          (cdr list))))                  ; next-step-expression
```

E.g. for a list of `'(gazelle giraffe lion tiger)`. The print order is `gazelle`, `giraffe`, `lion`, `tiger`.

However, I could not understand why the same order still holds when I switch the position of the two expression within the `when` body:

```
(defun print-elements-recursively (list)
   "Print each element of LIST on a line of its own.
 Uses recursion."
   (when list                            ; do-again-test
                       ; body
         (print-elements-recursively     ; recursive call
          (cdr list))
         (print (car list))))                  ; next-step-expression
```

Per my expectation, the recursion happens before the `print` function, therefore, the order should be reversed. May I know why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. After evaluating the first `defun` the order of items is `gazelle` ... `tiger`, and after evaluating the second `defun` the order is reversed. I suggest you rename one of the `defun`s, evaluate them both and then call each one of them separately. Does the behavior persist when you do that?

Comment: @itsjeyd, I see. Indeed the 2nd execution after name change generated results as expected.

Comment: OK great, I'll post my comments as an answer then :)

Comment: I don't see why you would get a lot of downvotes for this question. You clearly stated what you were trying to do, and what your problem was, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably did not evaluate the second `defun` after defining it, and that is why the items of the input list are still being printed in the original order. Adding a second function with the same name to the global namespace does not mean that the definition of the first function is automatically overwritten.

I suggest you

- rename one of the `defun`s
- evaluate them both
- and then call each one of them separately.

The behavior should not persist when you do that.

---

Aside from printing the elements of the list in a different order, note also that the original function returns `nil` and the second function returns a `print`ed representation of the last (non-`nil`) item of the input list. This is because `(when list)` returns `nil` and is the last expression that gets evaluated when the base case is reached in the first function. In the second function all invocations of `print` are evaluated *after* the base case is reached.